# Prevent infinite loops in hash chains?

Tags: git, hash, timestamp, infinite-loop

Okay, so I want to implement a simple network algorithm where each participant chooses its peers and takes turns looking at their latest hashes producing a chain of hashes of itsown, like this:

```
H[n+1] = hash( H[n] + P[n][k] )
```

Where `P[n][k]` was the latest hash of the chosen peer. Let's call this "timestamping".

The point of this is to produce a network that proves an event `A` happened before an event `B`, or vice versa, by generating a chain of hashes from `A` to `B`. The network does this in a permissionless manner - meaning if any participant timestamps your event `A`, then eventually they all do.

The problem I am facing is that if participant `X2` timestamps `X1`, `X3` timestamps `X2` and so on, if `X[n]` is really peer `X1` this may double back on itself and they keep on timestamping themselves in cycles even though no new events were really submitted.

This same issue happens with git or mercurial when I merge my changes from fork `B` back into `A`, producing a new hash, then merge the head (tip) of `A` into `B`, and so on. In other words nothing changed in the working copy but each new merge produces a new hash, causing fake change.

Mercurial kind of prevents it by going back checking the last time anything "really changed". Meaning, if no files changed since the last commit on the branch, it basically says something like "merging with direct ancestor has no effect".

I can likewise prevent cycles by traversing back the whole hash chain until I may find a cycle. But this may be a really long traversal. If I cut it off at, say, 10 hashes then cycles of 11 or more participants will still result in cycles of hashing even though nothing really "changed". Or maybe I may have some notion of "really changed".

Is there any way to address this, or some terms to google for?

Comment: Mercurial and Git always add *new* hashes: they never re-use an existing one for a new commit. If your new hash is truly new it cannot be part of a loop. This particular test, however, requires knowing all existing hashes (which Git and Hg do). Your case sounds a bit different.

Comment: Wat do you mean if your hash is truly new it can't be part of a loop? My point is not that the hashes repeat but that the participants keep making new hashes even though no new things have really changed.

Comment: Git and Mercurial identify a commit by its ID. If the commit is new, and its two parents are not, we've added a new node to the graph, and since the two edges of the new node are outbound only, that node is not part of a cycle (to be part of a cycle there must be some inbound edge). Assume that the initial graph has no cycles, that all nodes are read-only once created, and this is the only method for adding a node: then by induction, the updated graph continues to have no cycles.

Comment: Obviously the DAG has no cycle by definition. I was using the word in a different sense: that you can endlessly merge A into B and B into a, even though there were no new changes to the files.

Comment: Right: but the point here is that in Git and Mercurial you don't just add a new commit for the heck of it. In your case you are going to have to do a search, because in your system you *do* add a new node just because you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need more metadata than just the hash to determine if it has come by a certain node already. This metadata could conceivably be part of the data that is hashed (in addition to just the "timestamp"). This way the authenticity of the metadata can be confirmed. In the case of git for example, the hashes are not just hashes over the hashes of the parent commits, but over the commit message, author/committer information, dates and tree hash as well.

As for terms to search for: Generally such systems (git, Mercurial, bitcoin, various filesystems etc.) use [Merkle Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) to implement transaction validation and integrity checks.

Comment: Yeah. In my system though, the whole point is that if one participant timestamps your stuff then they all do. You can either include the hash published by a neighbor, or not. If you don't, then they won't include yours and you are effectively separated from that neighbor now. If yes, then your hash helps confirm all the events that the neighbor timestamped happened earlier. So how do I force these guys to take also the metadata? They may be timestamping 1000000 events (earlier in the DAG) by including that one hash. The metadata of all those various things would be huge. What to do?

Comment: Well, you say "earlier in the DAG" but your problem stems from the fact that it actually isn't a DAG, i.e. it is not acyclic. At the core, and that is what you refer to with your Mercurial example as well, is the problem of detecting when "no work is to be done". For this you need some kind of data. Maybe you could split the hashes into two types? One type would be "a hash validating a transaction" while the other one would be "a hash validating a peer hash". Then you could determine that no work is to be done when all of the hashes you get are only peer validation hashes?